# Minimum nodes in a n-ary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I know the formula for finding the maximum number of nodes in a n-ary tree given the height ( a tree containing either n nodes or none per node): (N^h+1)-1/(N-1). But how would you find the minimum number of nodes in a tree given the height and N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that this isn't homework (since you didn't phrase it as if it were) but is to satisfy your curiosity.

To start the tree you need 1 node. To keep it growing you need a minimum of N new nodes per level. Since you are trying to minimize the total number of nodes, the total is thus

```
1 + N + N + .... + N = 1 + h*N
```

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the minimum number is a tree in which only one node has children and the rest have none.

Comment: But OP stipulated that a node either has 0 children or n children

Comment: Hints are not SO answers. You should make it a comment instead.

Comment: @DavidBetz sorry I am used to math.SE answers